# dartlang interop js and d3 integration not working in dart

Tags: d3.js, interop, dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to get a simple `d3.js` snippet working in AngularDart. I have a simple component:

```
@NgComponent(...)
class LineChart {
  Element element;
  List<num> _items;
  var d3;

  @NgOneWayOneTime('data')
  set results ( List<num> results ) {
    _items = results;
    _drawLineChart(_items);
  }

  LineChart(this.element) {
    d3 = context['d3'];
    var temp = d3.callMethod('selectAll', [new JsObject.jsify([element])]);
    var temp1 = temp.callMethod('append', ['div']);
    temp1.callMethod('html', ['Hello Me']);
  }
}
```

I get the following error where `temp1` variable should be created. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I used [this](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/) tutorial as a reference.

```
NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.

STACKTRACE:
#0      JsObject._callMethod (dart:js:235)
#1      JsObject.callMethod (dart:js:225)
#2      JsObject.callMethod (dart:js:228)
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a small example without Angular? If so, then it might be a bug in dart:js and I can take a look.

Comment: @JustinFagnani I can try to do that. When a few days ago I was debugging this, I came to the point where I think it's actually chromium & chrome bug. I need to write a smaller snippet though to demonstrate.

Answer (score 2):

[According to the Dart API reference for `JsObject.jsify()`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart-js.JsObject@id_JsObject-jsify):

> Recursively converts a JSON-like collection of Dart objects to a collection of JavaScript objects and returns a `JsObject` proxy to it.
>
> `object` must be a `Map` or `Iterable`, the contents of which are also converted. Maps and Iterables are copied to a new JavaScript object. Primitives and other transferrable values are directly converted to their JavaScript type, and all other objects are proxied.

When you call:

```
var temp = d3.callMethod('selectAll', [new JsObject.jsify([element])]);
```

you don't need to `.jsify` the element because, according to the [API reference for `dart:js`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart-js):

> Proxying and automatic conversion
>   When setting properties on a JsObject or passing arguments to a Javascript method or function, Dart objects are automatically converted or proxied to JavaScript objects. When accessing JavaScript properties, or when a Dart closure is invoked from JavaScript, the JavaScript objects are also converted to Dart.
>
> Functions and closures are proxied in such a way that they are callable. A Dart closure assigned to a JavaScript property is proxied by a function in JavaScript. A JavaScript function accessed from Dart is proxied by a JsFunction, which has a apply method to invoke it.
>
> The following types are transferred directly and not proxied:
>
> - "Basic" types: null, bool, num, String, DateTime
> - Blob
> - Event
> - HtmlCollection
> - ImageData
> - KeyRange
> - Node
> - NodeList
> - TypedData, including its subclasses like Int32List, but not ByteBuffer
> - Window

The `Element` inherits from `Node` and is automatically converted. So you simply need to call:

```
var temp = d3.callMethod('selectAll', [element]);
```

also you don't need to create temporary variables because dart has shortcuts! You can do this:

```
LineChart(this.element) {
  d3 = context['d3'];
  d3.callMethod('selectAll', [element])
    .callMethod('append', ['div'])
    .callMethod('html', ['Hello Me']);
}
```